# Checking for a condition in signals.py using a variable passed in a method existing in views.py - django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-signals

I'm trying to evaluate a situation here. I have a custom user Model (Using AbstractUser) that contains an extra field called 'role'. I can access the value of this field in `views.py` using a variable. Now I want to use that variable to check for a condition in `signals.py` before executing `post_save`.
Here are my code snippets so far.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test, login_required

# Create your views here.
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        register_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if register_form.is_valid():
            register_form.save()
            username = register_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            role = register_form.cleaned_data.get('role') //**This is the variable**
            messages.success(request, f'Welcome {username}, thank you for signing up.')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        register_form = UserRegisterForm()

    context = {
        'register_form' : register_form,
        'title' : 'Register'
    }

    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Teacher

User = get_user_model()
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_teacher(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if hasattr(instance, 'role') and role == 'teacher': //Here is the condition
            Teacher.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_teacher(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.teacher.save()
```

Can someone please help me on how to go about it? Thanks

Comment: Do you need to do this in a signal? It would be much clearer if you did it directly in the view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes because I want it such that if the condition is met, then an object is created in the teacher model

Comment: But why does that mean it needs to be done in the signal? Why can't you create the teacher in the view, where you know the value of role?

Comment: The scenario is, when creating a new User, if the role is 'teacher', then a signal should trigger an object to be created in the Teacher Model with an instance if that particular user

Comment: Yes. You've now said that three times. And as I've said twice, **why don't you do that directly in the view**?

Comment: Would you give me a suggestion on how to do that in the views then please?

Comment: The same way you're doing it in the signal, mostly... test the value of role and do whatever appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make this much harder than it needs to be. Just create the teacher in the view.

```
if register_form.is_valid():
    instance = register_form.save()
    username = register_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
    role = register_form.cleaned_data.get('role')
    if role == 'teacher':
        Teacher.objects.create(user=instance)
    messages.success(request, f'Welcome {username}, thank you for signing up.')
    return redirect('home')
```

Comment: How do I define that instance?

Comment: Define what instance?

Comment: this instance
`Teacher.objects.create(user=instance)`